# Are there any differences relating to query performance between >= and <= vs. Between clause?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, index-tuning

Are there any performance-related differences between those two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM `v1` WHERE `siteId`=1008 AND `date`>='2022-10-01' and `date`<='2023-02-01';
```

```
SELECT * FROM `v1` WHERE `siteId`=1008 AND `date` between '2022-10-01' and '2023-02-01';
```

The output of `EXPLAIN` is the same; currently, I have 8M rows, and this number will increase to around 50M rows.

Below is the applied index:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...  BETWEEN ...;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

you will see that the parser turns `BETWEEN...AND...` into `...>=...AND ... <= ...`.  Hence, the two formulations are identical in performance.

I suggest that `date<='2023-02-01'` (and the equivalent `BETWEEN`) is a mistake.  Did you really want a range of months, *plus* the first day of the next month?  I like this formulation:

```
WHERE `date` >= '2022-10-01'
  AND `date`  < '2022-10-01' + INTERVAL 4 MONTH;
```

To do even better than the index you suggest, I would have

```
PRIMARY KEY(sideId, date),   -- even faster for the query you presented
INDEX(id)    -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Comment: Thanks, I should query by any days not only beginning of the month. Secondly, my data is hourly based meaning I have 24 sample for each (siteId and date), however hours not included in my main query.

Answer (score 0):

There should be negligible difference between the two forms. They are optimized the same.

Performance is influenced most heavily by the number of rows examined, and an index will help both forms of predicate reduce the examined rows in the same way, using a **range optimization**.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html

> ...for BTREE indexes, comparison of a key part with a constant value is a range condition when using the `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `BETWEEN`, `!=`, or `<>` operators, or `LIKE` comparisons if the argument to `LIKE` is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character.

But the proof is in the pudding, so to speak. There might be minor differences specific to your query, your data, or your server. If you doubt the performance equivalence, you should test yourself.

You might like to use the [query profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html) to measure execution time more precisely.

Comment: thanks, for now both perform very well. The conclusion is, I can use either of them, when the samples increases in the future I should revaluate it again. Am I current, or I miss something?

Comment: Yes, they should continue to have the same performance no matter how large the database gets.

Comment: I have yet to find an example of `PROFILE` that provided me with any helpful info.

Comment: Profiling is a good way to isolate query execution time from other latency, such as lock time or network time. Also it helps to  know which phase it's spending its time. I've seen queries that surprised me because they spent a lot of time optimizing (because of a very long `IN()` list), or not so surprising because the great majority of time was spent in building a temp table.